# Трудности с отступом - IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python, отступы

Ошибка отступа, не могу понять почему( Может кто поможет? Вот часть кода. Благодарен за ваши ответы.

```
try:
    user.login('password')
except (wa.CaptchaRequired, wa.LoginIncorrect) as exp:
    if isinstance(exp, LoginIncorrect):
        # ask for new password
    else:
        password = self.password

    if isinstance(exp, wa.CaptchaRequired):
        print user.captcha_url
        # ask a human to solve captcha
    else:
        captcha = None

    user.login(password=password, captcha=captcha)
except wa.EmailCodeRequired:
    user.login(email_code='ZXC123')
except wa.TwoFactorCodeRequired:
    user.login(twofactor_code='ZXC123')
```

Строка ошибки 4 "    else:"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В коде на Python не должно быть пустых или состоящих только из комментариев блоков кода (например, внутри `if`). Нужно добавить хотя бы `pass`:

```
if isinstance(exp, LoginIncorrect):
    # ask for new password
    pass
else:
    password = self.password
```